# Recreating the activity on orientation change

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, orientation, manifest

in manifest i added

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

but when i change orientation, This disables the layout change. How do I fix that?

and i created landscape using landscape qualifier, so both have same name but in land folder and normal.
So calling

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

wont work.

i need activity to choose portrait and lanscape mode from corresponding xml and without rcreating activity on orientation change.

Comment: by using the configChanges, you're telling Android not to recreate the Activity and load the new appropriate matching resources. i guess you could make a layout/activity_main_landscape and set your content view to that in onConfigurationChange.